# Strange behavior from affine transform rotation on iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I want to do a fairly simple rotation of a UIImageView.  Basically I have an image of a wheel in a perfectly square image and I want to rotate it under animation.

So I tried this:

```
- (void)testButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Test button pressed");
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         dial.transform = transform;  // "dial" is a UIImageView
                     }
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
 }
```

What happens is that, when the animation begins the image (that's about 300 square) immediately jumps up 50-100 pixels and is "squeezed" into a narrow oval.  After that, the animation proceeds just fine.

I tried using `beginAnimation` instead and got the same behavior.

I understand that I don't understand the stuff about the rotation origin (the docs talk in circles), but the squeezing seems odd, and the fact that it all occurs at once (vs being animated) is strange.

Any ideas?

(This is running on the iPhone 6.0 simulator from Xcode 4.5.1.  Is is possibly just a simulator thing?)

**Update:**  I got a chance to work on it a little more (I do it in-between "real" work).  I created a new XIB that never had autolayout and the wheel was "normal" but the background was vertically compressed.

Then a bit of inspiration.  I noticed that the image views were marked "autoresize" in the NLog dumps.  Didn't see a way to turn that off from IB, but did see that you can turn off "Autoresize Subviews" on the main view.  Did that and it behaved perfectly!

I'm thinking that some of the new features introduced for autolayout are the culprit here.  Don't know, though, if I've found all the magical settings yet.

**But...**  Still have the problem that the "transparent" parts of my images are black on the iPad, even after turning off "Opaque" on everything.

**Update:** I've finally figured out that my images were in JPG 24 bit mode rather than 32 bit mode.  This works on the simulator -- pure black is interpreted as transparent.  But it doesn't work on the iPad.  Using 32 bit images fixes that and (with "autoresize subviews turned off to eliminate the odd distortions/translations) everything is fine ***except*** ... rotations > 180 degrees animate backwards.  The animation is being "smart" and taking the "shortest path".

I suppose I'll simply have to break the animation into two steps.

Comment: I tried you code on a square UIImage view, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Hmmm.  I made the image smaller (with more margin) and it doesn't distort, but it jumps down and to the right when starting.

Comment: Made it smaller still and the image jumps down a bunch.  But the odder thing is that the image behind it (which is not being animated) is squeezed horizontally.  This is about as vanilla a setup as I can conceive of.

Comment: If I make the background image smaller it doesn't distort, but now the wheel is jumping down to the right again.

Comment: Well, it gets stranger.  Occurred to me to turn off autolayout, and then the jumping stops, but on the iPhone simulator the image starts out squashed vertically and displaced upward.  On the iPad simulator (with iPad xib), however, it works perfectly.  But on a real iPad (don't have an iPhone of the right version handy) it works, but the transparent parts of the images are black (and not transparent).

Comment: @Hot Licks to fix the black background problem try setting the UIImageView "Opaque" property to true or "YES" and explicitly set the background color to "clearColor." You can do this in code or in interface builder. This also applies for UILabel. I do that all the time for UILabel.

Comment: @RyanM - I already had the background "clear".  "Opaque" was already on and I tried it off, with no change.  But I'm suspecting it has something to do with the images I have.  They're PNGs and show up with transparency on the simulator, but when I inspect them with Irfanview they're 24 bit, not 32 bit.  I went back and resaved them (from Pixelformer) as 32 bit, but I won't be able to try them until Monday.

Comment: I had a similar squeezing problem during a CABasicAnimation rotation sequence with retina PNG's on iPad. It simply was gone with Hot Licks "Autoresize subviews" setting to off. It seems there is an issue with the CALayer manipulation when subviews are autoresized.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it with CABasicAnimation.

```
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: -M_PI_2 ];
rotationAnimation.duration = 2.0;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0; 
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

[imageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```